# Celery throws connection reset by peer error

Tags: python-2.7, celery

I have a kombu consumer which sends a task periodically to my celery application(using rabbitmq backend) as such:

```
celery_app.send_task('fetch_data', args=[], kwargs={})
```

The celery app receives the task and is able to execute it. However after a while when it receives another task in a similar fashion, I get a

```
[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

In the rabbitmq logs I see a lot of heartbeat missed warnings.
I have already tried setting

```
broker_pool_limit = None
```

in my celery app, but it did not solve the problem.
How do I rectify this?